# SQL Server turkish character situation

Tags: sql, sql-server, collate, sql-server-collation

I am having a Turkish Character problem in ASP.NET and SQL Server. I have searchbox in asp.net and trying to do a search in database. However, I am having problems in Turkish characters. When I search for "GALVANİZ" which contains illegal "İ" character. the word "GALVANİZ" is in the database, I am sure.

When I do a simple select statement in SQL Server tool, it doesn't return anything either.

Here is the SQL

```
select * from Product where name like '%GALVANİZ%'
```

This doesn't return anything. How can I get it fixed?

thanks

Comment: Which collation are you using?  Is it `Turkish_CI_AI`?

Comment: I didnt do any collation thing. Should I choose the collation when I create tables? or should I do it when selecting?

Comment: You can do either.  You could also try your query like this `where name like N'%GALVANİZ%'` with N in front of the characters to indicate Unicode.

Comment: thank you very much. it works but can you give me a more proper way to do it? what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Ensure that you use unicode text in your queries (by prepending the 'N' character before the string) in order to indicate that the text should be treated as Unicode.  I will add this is a proper answer (so you can mark it as answered).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can specify a collation in your query such as `Turkish_CI_AI`, or alternatively use the 'N' character with your strings to indicate that they are Unicode, as so:

```
select * from Product where name like N'%GALVANİZ%'
```

Comment: I will mark it in 5 mins. when I do the select in mssql tool, it works. but when I do it in C# code, it doesnt work. why do you think it doesnt work in c# code

Comment: Could you update your original question with the C# code you are using so I could take a look at it?  Thanks!

Comment: I used only N and it is working for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

I solved the question myself too. here is the solution

```
select * from product where name like N'%GALVANi%' collate Turkish_CI_AS
```

this is a much better solution

Answer (score 0):

sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-collation
enter collation: Turkish_CI_AS
sudo systemctl start mssql-server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, putting `N` in front of the search text will work. But in such a case you will have to use `N` constantly.

If you want it to find unicode characters in all cases (Turkish, Russian, Greek, Japanese, Arabic, etc.), your choice for DB Collation should be the UTF8 ones for the latin series.
for example: `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_SC_UTF8`

This way you don't have to use the prefix `N` when searching.